# Calls to OnPrepareOptionsMenu yields null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Each time I call `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();` My application will foreclose due to a null pointer exception.

My goal is to change Action Settings based on the fragment that is called via the ListView within my Navigational Drawer.

My OnPrepareOptionsMenu method is as follows:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    if (mNumber == 1) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.sortByDivision).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.sortByFighter).setVisible(false);
    }
    if (mNumber == 2) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.sortByDivision).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.sortByFighter).setVisible(true);
    }
    if (mNumber == 3) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.sortByDivision).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.sortByFighter).setVisible(false);
    }
    if (mNumber == 4) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.sortByDivision).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.sortByFighter).setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
    //return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Calls to this method are as follows:

```
  @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                //getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                //getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
```

I can post more code or whole file if necessary.  My logcat points to the first menu.findItem… statement that is not commented out.

```
05-27 16:50:17.898  25117-25117/com.MMA E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.MMA, PID: 25117
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.MMA.BMMA.onPrepareOptionsMenu(BMMA.java:129)
            at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2564)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:464)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a while but I figured it out.  I was making calls to change my action bar items when the view was not loaded which resulted in me calling values that don't exist.  I fixed this with an if statement that wouldn't allow my on prepare method to do anything until the there is a value in the view.

Efficient?.. probably not.  Did it work?  YES!

```
 if(menu.findItem(R.id.sortByDivision) != null && menu.findItem(R.id.sortByFighter) != null) {
            if (mNumber == 1) {
                menu.findItem(R.id.sortByDivision).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sortByFighter).setVisible(false);
            }

            if (mNumber == 2) {
                menu.findItem(R.id.sortByDivision).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sortByFighter).setVisible(true);
            }
            if (mNumber == 3) {

                menu.findItem(R.id.sortByDivision).setVisible(true);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sortByFighter).setVisible(false);
            }
            if (mNumber == 4) {
                menu.findItem(R.id.sortByDivision).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sortByFighter).setVisible(false);
            }
        }
        return true;
        //return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` ?

Do you inflate the menu ? Maybe try like this `getmenuinflater().inflate(r.menu.main menu)`.

Also double check the id of the menu item.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I figured it out.